# Call a Javascript function on load of JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

Can i call a javascript function on load of a JSP file according to a request parameter value?
I want to send a request from my Servelt to the JSP and if the value of a parameter="something" i want to call a specific JS function.
Is that possible? Please send me any relevant example if it is available.

thnks in advance

Comment: This question is much easier to answer yourself if you realize that JSP is merely a HTML/JS code generator.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question i assume this is what you want try it

```
<%
    String text = request.getParameter("parameter");

    %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
     var text1="<%=text%>";
    if(text1.length>0)
    {

    //do what you want call function or something

    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer byut the problem didn't solved, i now get the error: uncaught type error:object#<HTMLDocument? has no method "getElementById" and i think that my JS function is not called.

Comment: Is that hidden input field absolutely necessary? This is just unnecessarily clumsy. Just print it directly as a JS variable. By the way, keep XSS in mind.

Comment: how could you pass a variable from server side coding to javascript and the value has to be used futher in if condition

Comment: You don't *pass* a variable from JSP to JS. You just let JSP *print* a JS variable. You (and the OP) seem to naively think that JSP and JS somehow run in sync at same environment or so. This is completely untrue. JSP is essentially a HTML code generator and JS is part of that HTML code.

Comment: I know that .. but I didnt get what you mean by print js variable when there is no js varaiable to print

Comment: @BalusC I have removed the input field .. is it ok now

Comment: Sry for the delay i was busy with Server side implementation i will check it out later and i will let you know thanks though :)